# How to add a string in between a url using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, url-encoding

I have a case like i need to add a string in between a url.

I have a url like `xyz.com/broadcast-images/233.jpg` and i want to rewrite the url as `xyz.com/1200/600/233.jpg`.

How can i do it purely in the reactjs based code?

Comment: you want to add dynamic values in a string ?

Comment: @MayankShukla yes this is a screen shot url and i want to modify the url by adding the above condition. just want to add 1200/600 after broadcast-images/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with vanilla js pretty easily, check out this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2smqq754/

```
function url(url) {
  url = 'xyz.com/broadcast-images/233.jpg';
  var match = '/broadcast-images';
  var base = url.indexOf(match);
  var matched_index = base + match.length;
  var formatted_url = url.substring(0, matched_index) + '/1200/600' + url.substring(matched_index, url.length);
  return formatted_url;
}
```